# what is Telerik Reporting Services and what actually needs to implemented in it?

Tags: telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting

I have been working with Telerik for a while but recently i have encountered about Telerik Reporting services.I'm most confused with telerik reporting services (REST and WCF)

What is Telerik Reporting Services  ?  A web services in a broad sense  is way that two software systems will communicate and exchange data by a certain mutual understanding protocol.But what we are achieving with telerik reporting services .What exactly one should implement in this web services  and consume

I was more worried and badly needed was what to be implemented in the service than how to implement it.Can any one tell me in an layman terms what we are implementing in the services .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telerik Reporting Services are a set of services that allow report generation from client applications.

Based on the technology there are:

- Telerik Reporting REST Service, which has two implementations based on ASP.NET WebAPI framework and ServiceStack. This service is designed for the purposes of the Telerik HTML5 Report Viewer. The service can be used directly by any third party client applications as well.
- Telerik Reporting WCF Service, which is based on Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) and is designed for the purposes of the Telerik Silverlight Report Viewer. The service can be used directly by any third party client applications as well.

You can find more information in the [Telerik Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/telerik-reporting-services.html)

Comment: can I use this report service from a Java application i.e can i consume already created report from Java

Comment: No, this is not possible, because Telerik Reporting requires .NET on the server

Comment: Can't I use Html Report  viewer outside .NET environment i.e. like in an simple HTML document or in  any Java application.One more question what exactly does the service return when i call to bind it to a report viewer

Comment: what does a Telerik reporting service returns when a report is accessed via Uri and does a running instance of reporting engine is required at the receiving end.(and also in the case of HTML5 report viewer)

Comment: Hello. You can find information about the service in the Telerik Reporting documentation: http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/telerik-reporting-rest-api.html. Note however that the service requires .NET and a running instance of the Telerik Reporting engine. Because of that the implementation of the service in a Java application probably will not work.